# In chkdsk, what is spot fixing?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, chkdsk

(Related to, but different from: [In chkdsk, what is an online scan?](https://superuser.com/questions/906222/in-chkdsk-what-is-an-online-scan).)

Running Windows 8.0 Pro, `chkdsk` has a `/spotfix` option that `Runs spot fixing on the volume`. What is spot fixing? If it relates to fixing the drive online, I thought `/scan` without `/forceofflinefix` handles that.

EDIT: It may be related to not fixing errors upon detection, but saving the spots and fixing them later.

Here's the full options:

```
CHKDSK [volume[[path]filename]]] [/F] [/V] [/R] [/X] [/I] [/C] [/L[:size]] [/B]
[/scan] [/spotfix]


  volume              Specifies the drive letter (followed by a colon),
                      mount point, or volume name.
  filename            FAT/FAT32 only: Specifies the files to check for
                      fragmentation.
  /F                  Fixes errors on the disk.
  /V                  On FAT/FAT32: Displays the full path and name of every
                      file on the disk.
                      On NTFS: Displays cleanup messages if any.
  /R                  Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information
                      (implies /F, when /scan not specified).
  /L:size             NTFS only:  Changes the log file size to the specified
                      number of kilobytes.  If size is not specified, displays
                      current size.
  /X                  Forces the volume to dismount first if necessary.
                      All opened handles to the volume would then be invalid
                      (implies /F).
  /I                  NTFS only: Performs a less vigorous check of index
                      entries.
  /C                  NTFS only: Skips checking of cycles within the folder
                      structure.
  /B                  NTFS only: Re-evaluates bad clusters on the volume
                      (implies /R)
  /scan               NTFS only: Runs a online scan on the volume
  /forceofflinefix    NTFS only: (Must be used with "/scan")
                      Bypass all online repair; all defects found
                      are queued for offline repair (i.e. "chkdsk /spotfix").
  /perf               NTFS only: (Must be used with "/scan")
                      Uses more system resources to complete a scan as fast as
                      possible. This may have a negative performance impact on
                      other tasks running on the system.
  /spotfix            NTFS only: Runs spot fixing on the volume
  /sdcleanup          NTFS only: Garbage collect unneeded security descriptor
                      data (implies /F).
  /offlinescanandfix  Runs an offline scan and fix on the volume.

The /I or /C switch reduces the amount of time required to run Chkdsk by
skipping certain checks of the volume.
```

Comment: online while the os is running vs running it while the os isn't running system (offline)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Windows 8 has built-in maintenance tasks that run every day. Windows 8 will check these verified corruptions and log them into the system for later fixing. Again, this is all done while the system is online. The next stage is **Spot Fix**. This is where chkdsk in Windows 8 is completely different. Spot Fix is a new parameter that checks the disk and fixes any problems in just a few seconds. The time it takes to run chkdsk using spotfix is based on the number of corruptions instead of the number of files as in older versions of Windows. This means everything is fixed in seconds.

Source: Online-Tech-Tips.com, [*The Online Tech Tips Guide to Chkdsk in Windows 8*](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/featured-posts/the-online-tech-tips-guide-to-chkdsk-in-windows-8/) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/1yXEv).)

Answer (score 2):

Spot fix means **just in time** fix.

In between the chkdsk process if the bug , error or any other problem is found out then its fix it by windows at a same time, that means as if the problem found then it instantly solved out.