# NTFS, chkdsk, check bad sectors and recover readable parts for only specified files?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ntfs, chkdsk

It is a large disk and it seems all files but a few are readable. For the few files, reading fails at the same point. Something like position 1.5GB of a 5GB file. The SMART data does show unrelocatable, so I guess it is a physical error. But I am pretty sure that not the entire non-readable 3.5GB are on bad sectors. Probably, the NTFS file system stops at the first bad sector it encountered.

So, I want to recover all the readable part of the files (non-readable parts could be filled with `0x00`). It seems that `chkdsk /f /r` would do it, but it takes tens of hours because it tries to scan the entire disk. I already know the names of the few files for which reading fails. Can't I do `/r` for only specified files, or at least specified directory?

> /r    Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information. The disk
> must be locked. /r includes the functionality of /f, with the
> additional analysis of physical disk errors.

Comment: I'd do a built-in diagnostic on the drive, if it fails I'd use `ddrescue` to recover the data since you can't fix the drive at that point & the more you access the drive the more likely it will fail further

Comment: @gregg  By build-in diagnostic can I assume you mean a S.M.A.R.T test. ?  (It may not be clear to the OP).  Absolutely agree with you.

Comment: Or use another cloning tool **running from a bootable drive**, such as Macrium Reflect's rescue USB drive. Operate on the *clone*, rather than further damaging the HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is a large disk and it seems all files but a few are readable. For the few files, reading fails at the same point. Something like position 1.5GB of a 5GB file. The SMART data does show unrelocatable, so I guess it is a physical error.

Please provide the relevant line out of your SMART report created with smartmontools. I never read the term "unrelocatable" in SMART reports.

### Solution 1

> So, I want to recover all the readable part of the files (non-readable parts could be filled with 0x00). It seems that chkdsk /f /r would do it,

I doubt that chkdsk will produce files in your desired output format.
The solution under linux could be to apply the **ddrescue** command individually to each broken file:

**ddrescue** brokenfile recoveredfile mapfile

where

- **ddrescue** is the command
- *brokenfile* is the full path to your brokenfile
- *recoveredfile* the full path to your recoveredfile, this should not reside on your device with broken files
- *mapfile* is logfile describing the current state of recovery and after finish will also denote the areas of the file that have been recovered

https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html states

*If the output file is a regular file created by ddrescue, the areas marked as bad-sector will contain zeros. If it is a device or a previously existing file, the areas marked as bad-sector will still contain the data previously present there.*

### Solution 2 (incomplete, only a possible hint)

There is a new parameter in chkdsk called "spotfix". I did not find any satisfying explanation of it. Running only legacy operating systems I can't run **chkdsk /?** to read the built-in help text. This might be of interest to you.

Comment: Well, I remembered the term incorrectly; it was "uncorrectable". Anyway, it turned out that you can't cancel chkdsk /r. The ETA was not accurate and it was finished. The result was that it found bad sectors and "Windows replaced bad clusters in file". Those files were all those I had known, except one new file whose file number was close. After this, reading did not fail at that location, and I could copy the entire files to a new drive. I had run spotfix before, but it did not find anything.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1027733/in-chkdsk-what-is-spot-fixing for a better description of `/spotfix`.